# Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Show that $\{(x,y)\in k^2\mid xy=0\}$ is closed and connected but not irreducible in $k^2$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

*This is **Exercise 1.2.8(3)** of Springer's, "Linear Algebraic Groups (Second Edition)". According to [this search on Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5C%7B(x%2Cy)%5Cin%20k%5E2%5Cmid%20xy%3D0%5C%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Airreducible&p=10), it is new to MSE. The exercise comprises of three parts, whose relationship with each other is, I believe, strong enough to include into one post here.*

### The Details:

Since definitions vary:

> A *topological space* $(X,\tau)$ is a set $\tau$ of subsets of $X$, called *closed subsets*, such that
>
> - $\varnothing, X\in\tau$,
> - The intersection $$\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i$$ of any closed subsets $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ is closed, where $I$ is arbitrary, and
> - The union of finitely many closed sets is closed.

Note that $\tau$ is omitted sometimes when the context is clear.

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field.

We denote by $\mathcal{V}(I)$ the set of all zeros of $I$.

The topology on $V:=k^n$ whose closed subsets are $\mathcal{V}(I)$ for ideals $I$ of $S:=k[T_1,\dots, T_n]$ is known as the *Zariski topology*.

On page 2 of Springer's book, **1.2.1** reads,

> A topological space $X\neq\varnothing $ is *reducible* if it is the union of two proper closed subsets. Otherwise $X$ is *irreducible*. A subset $A\subset X$ is irreducible if it is irreducible for the induced topology. Notice that $X$ is irreducible if and only if any two nonempty open subsets of $X$ have a nonempty intersection.

On page 4, **1.2.7** reads,

> [A] topological space is *connected* if it is not the union of two disjoint proper closed subsets.

### The Question:

> Let $$X=\{(x,y)\in k^2\mid xy=0\}.$$ Show that $X$ is a closed subset of $k^2$ which is connected but not irreducible, all with respect to the Zariski topology.

### Thoughts:

Since $xy$ is a polynomial $f$ in $x,y$ with coefficients in $k$, we have $X=\mathcal{V}((f))$. Hence $X$ is closed under the Zariski topology.

For connectedness, I can start as follows. If $k=\Bbb R$, then $X$ is the union of the $x$-axis with the $y$-axis; this is clearly connected under the usual topology on $\Bbb R^2$. I'm not sure where to go from here.${}^\dagger$

A similar consideration strikes me for reducibility: We can write

$$X=\mathcal V((g))\cup\mathcal V((h))$$

for $g=x$ and $h=y$.

Please help :)

---

$\dagger$: I am aware that $\Bbb R$ is not algebraically closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, $X$ is the union of the closed sets $A=\{(x,y)\in k^2: x=0\}$ and $B=\{(x,y)\in k^2: y=0\}$, and so it is reducible.

Since $A$ and $B$ have a common point, it is sufficient to show they are both connected, and this will imply that $X$ is connected as well. So let's show $A=\{(0,y): y\in k\}$ is connected. Clearly it is sufficient to prove $A$ is irreducible, which is equivalent to the ideal $I(A)\subseteq k[x,y]$ being a prime ideal. And indeed, it can be shown that $I(A)=(x)$, the ideal generated by $x$. The right hand side is clearly contained in the left hand side. Conversely, suppose that $f(x,y)\in I(A)$, i.e $f(0,y)=0$ for all $y\in k$. Write:

$f(x,y)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n f_i(x)y^i$

So the polynomial $f(0,y)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n f_i(0)y^i\in k[y]$ vanishes at all points of $k$. Since $k$ is an infinite field (it is algebraically closed) it follows that $f(0,y)$ must be the zero polynomial, i.e $f_i(0)=0$ for all $i$. But this exactly means that all the polynomials $f_i(x)$ are divisible by $x$, and so $f$ is divisible by $x$ as well. So indeed $f\in (x)$.